# Como mostrar solo este año de mi tabla de sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos dias, tengo una table en sql donde tengo fechas desde 1990 hasta el 2016
entonces quiero solo este año o el 2015,pero tambien quiero cierto tipo de camiones , entonces he intentado realizando las siguientes consultas asi:

1. Así es para sacar solo las fechas y lo hace bien

   ```
   SELECT * FROM cas where fecha>'2016-01-01' order by fecha desc
   ```

   o

   ```
   select * FROM cas WHERE YEAR (fecha)='2016'
   ```

Y funciona

2. Entonces agrego el `where` de que tipo y la fecha así y no funciona me trae de otros años.

   ```
   select * from cas where fecha>'2016-01-01' and tipo='nissan' or tipo='ford' order by fecha desc
   ```

Alguien podria ayudarme en solo mostrar los tipos de ese año, sin que me traiga todos los años 2000
Espero su ayuda gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es la precedencia de los operadores lógicos en SQL, donde el `and` tiene mayor precedencia que el `or`, por tanto tu sentencia se evalúa como si estuviera escrito así:

```
select * from cas where (fecha > '2016-01-01' and tipo = 'nissan') or tipo = 'ford';
```

Para resolverlo, prueba esto:

```
select * from cas where fecha>'2016-01-01' and (tipo='nissan' or tipo='ford')
```

De esa manera, fuerzas a que evalúe primero las condiciones con `or` (sobre el tipo) y finalmente el `and`.

Comment: gracias funciono :) Dios te bendiga lindo dia :)

Comment: Con gusto, recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta para alguien mas que tenga una pregunta similar.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es muy simple, en el momento en que tu último `OR` es evaluado como `true`, entonces todo el `WHERE` es `true`. Necesitas usar paréntesis cuando quieras usar `OR` en conjunto con `AND`. Y en tu caso, ni siquiera necesitas el `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cas 
WHERE fecha >= '2016-01-01' 
AND tipo IN ('nissan','ford')
ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

Comment: GRACIAS, no em funciono asi, pero ya obtuve la ayuda, muchas gracias, bendiciones :)

Comment: @AraceLiTorres No entiendo bien cómo puede no haber funcionado, siendo que se expande a lo mismo que la otra consulta, pero me alegro que hayas obtenido ayuda

Comment: marcaba error en el and de tipo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con este ejemplo, la clave esta en la funcion YEAR y GETDATE

```
USE PRUEBA
GO


declare @año  varchar(20)
declare @inicioaño varchar(20)
set @año = year(getdate());
print @año
set @inicioaño = '01/01/'+@año
print @inicioaño

select * from facturas
where fecha >=convert(date, @inicioaño)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.. pero esta publicacion es bastatnte vieja, y lo que estas contestando no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta. y las otras dos respuestas, ya cubren el problema.. que agrega esto a lo que no dicen las otras dos?